# How can I append multiple columns to a dataframe with column names from a specific vector?

Tags: r

For example, I have a dataframe with 2 columns. I need to append 82 additional columns to this dataframe, with specific column names. These column names are stored in a different vector (dates). How can I do this efficiently? I tried the following:

```
for(i in 1:length(dates)) {
    peekdata<-cbind(peekdata,dates[i]=0
}
```

I'm fairly new to R so apologies if its a stupid question

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without a loop.

First, define some sample data

```
peekdata  <- data.frame(orig=1:5)
dates <- letters[1:10]
```

Now do

```
cbind(peekdata, setNames(replicate(length(dates), 0, simplify=F), dates))
```

to get

```
  orig a b c d e f g h i j
1    1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2    2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3    3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4    4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5    5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

But it's odd that you would be doing this. Are you going to fill in values later? Because is usually easier to calculate the values all at once and add them in rather than starting off with a bunch of zeros.

Comment: This worked! Thanks! The reason I'm doing it this way is because I have to match a bunch of the data from a different dataframe based on the specific dates and product IDs.